# Zoom controls on mermaid in docusaurus

Tags: zooming, docusaurus, mermaid

I installed the [@docusaurus/theme-mermaid](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/diagrams#configuration) plugin in DocuSaurus and rendered my diagram. However, due to the size of the diagram its view becomes small and the zoom and expansion controls are not enabled.

I have read the documentation and found nothing about it.
Does anyone know how to enable zoom?

```
sequenceDiagram
par Alice to Bob
    Alice->>Bob: Go help John
and Alice to John
    Alice->>John: I want this done today
    par John to Charlie
        John->>Charlie: Can we do this today?
    and John to Diana
        John->>Diana: Can you help us today?
    end
end
```

Comment: @Dr.Strangelove unfortunately not, in my case, I partitioned it into smaller pieces and offered an entire view without the feature. If you find, please, update this topic with the anwser.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know; yes, it is a bit tricky!

Answer (score 0):

I applied a static zoom to a parent div to increase the size

````
<div style={{overflowX: 'auto'}}>
<div style={{width: '200%'}}>

```mermaid
...YOUR MERMAID CODE...
```

</div>
</div>
````